# Remove junk characters (probably BOM) from xml file - VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, base64

I'm using the below code to write an XML file from a decoded Base64 string:

```
'More Code Above
btArr = MyFoundString

Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set EL = DM.createElement("tmp")
EL.DataType = "bin.base64"

EL.Text = CStr(btArr)
decodeBase64 = EL.nodeTypedValue

XMLFileName = FLDR_NAME & XMLFileNameF


Open XMLFileName For Binary Access Write As #1
Put #1, 1, decodeBase64
Close #1
```

The file gets written correctly, except for 12 junk characters that appear at the beginning of the file, thus rendering the xml file unusable:

[image: Junk Characters]

Each time it is a different 12 characters but each created file has them :(

After research, I understand that this might be format encoding related, and that these characters might constitute the Byte Order Mark (BOM).

How does one go about removing these characters?

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks, but that wouldn't really work because in this case `decodeBase64` is a Byte string that is written to file, and it isn't a text string from which you can omit characters.

Comment: FWIW - I just read up on base64 encoding, and ran your code substituting  `btArr = MyFoundString` with `btArr = "QUJD"` and it correctly wrote the 3 characters `"ABC"` to the file (with no stuff in front).  So that seems to imply that you have 8 characters at the start of `MyFoundString` which is generating the 12 characters in your output file.

Comment: Oops - just reread my last comment - that should read 16 characters generating the 12 characters.  (Possibly 2 x 8-byte words, or 1 x 16-byte word, of type information or size information?)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for trying to help. I figured it out, and posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was indeed in the way that the file was being written.

The solution was to change the below part:

```
Open XMLFileName For Binary Access Write As #1
Put #1, 1, decodeBase64
Close #1
```

To:

```
Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

BinaryStream.Type = 1

BinaryStream.Open
BinaryStream.Write decodeBase64
BinaryStream.SaveToFile XMLFileName, 2
```

After this all the files are written correctly using the ADODB stream method instead of the Binary Access write without any junk characters.